# Cypress write into an excel (.xslx) file

Tags: excel, file, cypress

I understand we can read data from excel using cypress. for this we convert it into json first and then read the data.

Is there a way to write data into excel (.xslx) file using cypress ?

Note: I want to perform write operation by appending data after the last occupied row in excel

Answer (score 0):

It's simple as `cy.writeFile('sheet.xlsx', 'Hellow World!')`. If you are converting your data format, then you'll have to add some code to handle that with something like [sheet.js](https://github.com/SheetJS/sheetjs) or something similar.

Comment: what if i want to append the data. Does cy.writeFile add the text to the last row by default ??

Comment: It might get tricky a bit there since it seems likely you will read the xlsx file, add some data, then write back to the file. There is a [`{ flag: 'a+' }`](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/writefile#Flags) you can set when appending to a file.

Comment: I'm curious, what is your end goal for having an excel sheet to store all your test data? I've used that approach for some data-driven testing in a previous company.

Comment: I am trying to create a historic trend in using graphs in excel. The test results from cypress need to be stored in excel for the same